# T-Sql Merge Command with a inner join. Can this be done?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge

I have a Stored procedure that uses the t-sql merge command.  The problem is that i need to merge on more then 1 table. I need to have a INNER JOIN in my target.  This is the code snippet of how it runs now 
This is how it looks now

```
WITH DealersCTE AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [DealershipName], [Dealer Zip] ORDER BY [DealershipName] ASC, [Dealer Zip] ASC) AS RowNum
        , [DealershipName]
        , [DAddress]

    FROM [DataFeedStaging2]
)

MERGE dbo.Dealers AS Target

USING (

        SELECT [DealershipName]
            ,[DAddress]


        FROM DealersCTE
        WHERE (RowNum = 1)

  ) AS Source

ON (Target.[CompanyName] = Source.[DealershipName] AND Target.[Zipcode] = Source.[Dealer Zip])
```

This is how i am trying to change it. Because the [VendorID] is being stored in another table I in my mind would need to do a Join before I could merge on that field.

```
WITH DealersCTE AS (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [VendorID] ORDER BY [VendorID] ASC, [VendorID] ASC) AS RowNum
            , [DealershipName]
            , [DAddress]            
            , [VendorID] 
        FROM [DataFeedStaging2]
    )

//The 2 lines below this where added as how i visioned it to work. 
//they do not work 
    MERGE  dbo.Dealers 
               inner join dbo.tblDataFeeds_External on dealers.dealerid = tblDataFeeds_External.dealerid AS Target

    USING (

            SELECT [DealershipName]
                ,[DAddress]             
                ,[VendorID]
            FROM DealersCTE
            WHERE (RowNum = 1)

      ) AS Source

    ON (Target. [VendorID] = Source. [VendorID])
```

Comment: Don't think you can do that.  You can certainly have joins in your `USING` clause.

Comment: @Andrew How can I Join on my Target?

Comment: **Maybe** you can do it by using a view (to implict join your tables) as target

Comment: @jean  Please move your comment to the answers. I want to make it as a correct answer. I used that and it worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using a view as target to implicit join your tables